AssertionError and ValueError in scikit-fuzzy,python
I am trying to build fuzzy logic with 3 input variables and one output variable in python.I have introduces 27 rules with the problem but I am getting the AssertionError: Total area is zero in defuzzification! error and I can't find the regarding problem. I have tried to remove variables and rules but the error remains still. Below is my code.

# Define universe 
sentiment_score_of_post_range = np.arange(1, -1,-0.01)
sentiment_score_of_comments_range = np.arange(1, -1,-0.01)
no_of_comments_range = np.arange(0,100,1)



# Define linguistic variables: post, comments,no_of_comments and influence
post = ctrl.Antecedent(sentiment_score_of_post_range, 'sentiment_score_of_post')
comments = ctrl.Antecedent(sentiment_score_of_comments_range, 'sentiment_score_of_comments')
no_of_comments = ctrl.Antecedent(no_of_comments_range, 'no_of_comments')

influence = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'influence')

#Define membership functions for sentiment score of post
post['low'] = fuzz.trimf(sentiment_score_of_post_range, [-1, -0.5, 0])
post['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(sentiment_score_of_post_range, [-0.7, 0.1, 0.5])
post['high'] = fuzz.trimf(sentiment_score_of_post_range, [0.5, 0.7, 1])

#Define membership functions for sentiment score of comments
comments['low'] = fuzz.trimf(sentiment_score_of_comments_range, [-1, -0.5, 0])
comments['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(sentiment_score_of_comments_range, [-0.7, 0.1, 0.5])
comments['high'] = fuzz.trimf(sentiment_score_of_comments_range, [0.5, 0.7, 1])


# Define membership functions for number of comments
no_of_comments['low'] = fuzz.trimf(no_of_comments_range, [0, 5, 15])
no_of_comments['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(no_of_comments_range, [15, 20, 50])
no_of_comments['high'] = fuzz.trimf(no_of_comments_range, [50, 70, 100])


# Define membership functions for influence (output)
influence['low'] = fuzz.trimf(np.arange(0, 11, 1), [0, 0, 3])
influence['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(np.arange(0, 11, 1), [2, 5, 8])
influence['high'] = fuzz.trimf(np.arange(0, 11, 1), [7, 10, 10])


rules = []

# Define fuzzy rules
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['high'] & comments['high'] & no_of_comments['high'], influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['high'] & comments['high'] & no_of_comments['medium'],influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['high'] & comments['high'] & no_of_comments['low'],influence['medium']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['high'] & comments['medium'] & no_of_comments['high'],influence['medium']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['high'] & comments['medium'] & no_of_comments['medium'],influence['medium']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['high'] & comments['medium'] & no_of_comments['low'],influence['low']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['high'] & comments['low'] & no_of_comments['high'],influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['high'] & comments['low'] & no_of_comments['medium'],influence['medium']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['high'] & comments['low'] & no_of_comments['low'],influence['low']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['medium'] & comments['high'] & no_of_comments['high'],influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['medium'] & comments['high'] & no_of_comments['medium'],influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['medium'] & comments['high'] & no_of_comments['low'],influence['medium']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['medium'] & comments['medium'] & no_of_comments['high'],influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['medium'] & comments['medium'] & no_of_comments['medium'],influence['low']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['medium'] & comments['medium'] & no_of_comments['low'],influence['low']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['medium'] & comments['low'] & no_of_comments['high'],influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['medium'] & comments['low'] & no_of_comments['medium'],influence['low']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['medium'] & comments['low'] & no_of_comments['low'],influence['low']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['low'] & comments['high'] & no_of_comments['high'],influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['low'] & comments['high'] & no_of_comments['medium'],influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['low'] & comments['high'] & no_of_comments['low'],influence['medium']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['low'] & comments['medium'] & no_of_comments['high'],influence['medium']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['low'] & comments['medium'] & no_of_comments['medium'],influence['medium']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['low'] & comments['medium'] & no_of_comments['low'],influence['medium']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['low'] & comments['low'] & no_of_comments['high'],influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['low'] & comments['low'] & no_of_comments['medium'],influence['high']))
rules.append(ctrl.Rule(post['low'] & comments['low'] & no_of_comments['low'],influence['low']))

# Create fuzzy control system
if(len(rules) > 0):
    influence_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem(rules=rules)
    influence_ctrl.view()
    influence_ctrl_sim = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(influence_ctrl)  


# Fuzzification: Provide input values
    influence_ctrl_sim.input['sentiment_score_of_post'] = round(0.10277777777777779,2)
    influence_ctrl_sim.input['sentiment_score_of_comments'] = round(0.09057175684352024,2)
    influence_ctrl_sim.input['no_of_comments'] = 32

# Apply fuzzy rules

    influence_ctrl_sim.compute()
    

# Defuzzification: Obtain crisp output

result = influence_ctrl_sim.output['influence']
print(result)



Below is the full error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/himash/Projects/Social-Computing-Seminar/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/skfuzzy/control/controlsystem.py", line 586, in defuzz
    return defuzz(ups_universe, output_mf,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/himash/Projects/Social-Computing-Seminar/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/skfuzzy/defuzzify/defuzz.py", line 248, in defuzz
    assert not zero_truth_degree, 'Total area is zero in defuzzification!'
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: Total area is zero in defuzzification!

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/himash/Projects/Social-Computing-Seminar/main.py", line 123, in <module>
    influence_ctrl_sim.compute()
  File "/Users/himash/Projects/Social-Computing-Seminar/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/skfuzzy/control/controlsystem.py", line 373, in compute
    CrispValueCalculator(consequent, self).defuzz()
  File "/Users/himash/Projects/Social-Computing-Seminar/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/skfuzzy/control/controlsystem.py", line 589, in defuzz
    raise ValueError("Crisp output cannot be calculated, likely "
ValueError: Crisp output cannot be calculated, likely because the system is too sparse. Check to make sure this set of input values will activate at least one connected Term in each Antecedent via the current set of Rules.

